# declaring background property in css twice

Tags: css

I am reverse engineering a previous employee's work and noticed a number of css classes look like this...

```
.img-shadow {
  float:left;
  background: url(../images/shadowAlpha.png) no-repeat bottom right !important;
  background: url(../images/shadow.gif) no-repeat bottom right;
}
```

Can anybody think of a reason for a css class to declare background twice like this (specifically with the !important)?

Comment: http://i55.tinypic.com/w858pd.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter#.21important_quirks), the second `background` rule is for IE6.

> Internet Explorer 6 and below also
>   have a problem with !important
>   declarations when the same property of
>   the same element has another value
>   specified within the same code block,
>   without another !important
>   declaration. This should result in the
>   second value being overridden by the
>   first, but IE6 and lower do not honor
>   this.

Comment: +1, for the most correct phrasing. Though most of the other answers do have the right idea, even if they aren't precisely correct/complete.

Comment: The classic usage of this "hack" is the [Min-Height Fast Hack](http://www.dustindiaz.com/min-height-fast-hack/).

Answer (score 1):

It's a cheap PNG fix for IE6.  Since IE6 won't recognize the `!important` tag, it will use the GIF background, while all other browsers will use the PNG.

Comment: AFAIK, IE6 in general *does* recognize `!important`, doesn't it? See my answer for full explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

[Older versions](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/importantdeclarations) of IE will use the last one.
These versions had problems with png transparency.

Comment: Nope, browsers don't choose background based on alhpa transparency -- at least i don't know any which do.

Comment: @Piotr I don't think you understood my answer.

Answer (score 0):

looks like he's attempting to support browsers that don't handle alpha .png's properly (*cough* IE6 *cough*)